# Spritekit frame long ground node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want a ground node that is as wide as the frame at all times. The code I have currently for it is;

```
    ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 175)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 1))
    ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ground
    ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ground
    ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ground
    self.addChild(ground)
```

How do I make it as wide as the frame?

Answer (score 0):

try this is resizes the width to whatever the size of your scene is or pretty much just the screen size

```
 ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: (scene?.size.width)!, height: ("specify your height"))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a rectangle for your ground physics shape vs. using an edge loop, I would recommend the ground rectangle be higher than 1 pixel. Especially with fast moving small physics objects there is the opportunity for that object to pass right through a 1 pixel physics object and not get detected.

also since you are adding the physicsBody to a sprite (ground) why not make the ground sprite the size you need and then make the physicsBody the size of the ground object

I am assuming that your anchorPoint is set to 0,0

```
ground.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: 175)
ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground.size())
```